# MATLAB code not working (gradient descent algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am trying gradient descent, I wrote following however not getting any answer,

```
n=0;            %initialize iteration counter 
eps=1;          %initialize error 
a=0.8;         %set iteration parameter 
x=[1;1];        %set starting value
f=6*x(1)^2+8*x(2)^2-3*x(1)*x(2);
%Computation loop 
while eps>1e-12||n<100 
   gradf=[12*x(1)-3*x(2); 16*x(2)-3*x(1)];  %gradf(x) 
   eps=(norm(gradf)/(1+abs(f)));                                %error 
   y=x-a*gradf;                                                 %iterate 
   x=y;                                                         %update x 
   n=n+1;                                                       %counter+1 
end 
n;x;eps;        %display end values
```

When I add this file to path and type x it shows NaN, NaN. what is wrong?

Comment: It seems to me gradient method doesn't always converge for constant 'a'. Try using another. Also, if you watch your 'eps' when debuggin you'll note it increasing to NaN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. Consider this (I put comments where corrections were needed)

```
 n=0;            
 eps=1;         
 a=0.1;                    %You need a way smaller parameter to converge!
 x=[1;1];       

 A = [6 -3/2 ; -3/2 8];     %You have a bilinear positive definite form,
                            %you may use matrix form for convenience


while eps>1e-12 && n<100    %You had wrong termination conditions!!
    gradf=2*A*x;            %(gradf in terms of matrix)
    f=x'*A*x;               %you need to update f every iteration!!
    eps=(norm(gradf)/(1+abs(f)))                              
    disp(eps > 1e-12)
    x=x-a*gradf;                                               

       %Now you can see the orbit  towards minimum                                     
    plot(x(1),x(2),'o'); hold on        
    n=n+1;                                                        
end 
n
x
eps
```

for instance with the current value `a=.1` I get

```
n = 100
eps = 1.2308e-011

x = 
  1.0e-012 *

  -0.2509
  0.4688
```

That is I had to perform 100 iteration because my epsilon is still above the threshold. If I allow 200 iterations I get

```
n =  110
eps = 
   7.9705e-013

x = 
1.0e-013 *
  -0.1625
   0.3036
```

I.e. 110 iterations are sufficient.

[image: Points get dense around the solution <code>(0,0)</code>]

---

Case of a general `f` (i.e. not a quadratic form).

You can use, for instance, [function handles](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html), i.e. you define (before the `while`)

```
foo = @(x) 6*x(1)^2+8*x(2)^2-3*x(1)*x(2);
foo_x = @(x) 12*x(1)-3*x(2); 
foo_y = @(x) 16*x(2)-3*x(1);
```

then, in the `while` you substitute

```
gradf = [foo_x(x);foo_y(x)];
f = foo(x);
```

---

P.S. for what concerns the `while` cycle, please keep in mind that you keep on iterating **while** you are not satisfied with your precision (`eps>1e-12`) **AND** your total number of iteration is below a given threshold (`n<100`).

Consider also that you are working in **finite precision**: a numerical algorithm can never reach the analytic solution (i.e. what you have with infinite precision and infinite iterations), therefore, you always have to **set a threshold** (`eps`, which should be above the machine precision \approx`1e-16`) and that **is** your `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Regarding "a", starting with 1, I am planning to update its value for every iteration by a factor 0.8.

Comment: Well, I don't see convergence with `a` bigger than `.1`. You can look at the orbit. Btw you may consider to accept the answer.

Comment: Well, the issue with too large `a`s is that your solution starts bouncing among large gradient zones and can't really converge. You should notice that your error estimator fails in those zone of big `f` .

Comment: what's wrong with the answer, now? why did you change your mind?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. But if we inspect the function the min answer should be 0 which is not obtained. and the termination conditions are "OR" not "AND"

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I could not understand the bilinear form and the way gradf and f are calculated. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Nick_R Sure I can. Are you familiar with linear algebra and matrices? You may consider [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), for instance. Quadratic forms (2nd degree polynomials, with no terms of degree 1 or 0) may be written using standard matrices operations. Indeed they are scalar products (if you are familiar with euclidean geometry).

Comment: If you compute the product  `x'*A*x ` (where  `x =[x(1);x(2)] ` and  ` `*` is the standard matrix multiplication operation) you will recover exactly your  `f`.

Comment: btw you can write  `f` and  `gradf` in the way you prefer. MATLAB is much faster when matrix operations are involved because it can rely on SIMD vectorization. Therefore it is always advisable to use matrix operations.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware (or can't remember) of a fact that we can represent quadratic functions in symmetric matrices form. how do we modify this code for general functions then?

Comment: @Nick_R the answer is updated. You can change the definition of `foo` and its gradient at your convenience. Now I'll have some rest. Please consider to accept the answer.